# Looking for help applying SOLID principles to a file I/O problem

Tags: c++, c++11, solid-principles

I am trying to learn more about design patterns and principles. I usually understand them in theory but I find myself having a hard time when it comes to applying them to a real-world problem. This is going to be a longer question to give all the relevant context and I would very much appreciate any advice on how to structure this properly.

Currently I am trying to implement a file manager (read and write) for a particular kind of structured file called a TextGrid (which is exported from a different software that I did not write) in Modern C++. This file can come in three different "flavors" (which all store the same information, just use different formats):

- Short text file
- Long text file
- Binary file

All flavors have the same extension. The user would normally not know which file they are dealing with and you have to read the beginning of the file to be able to tell the difference.

Now I understand that it makes sense in general to separate the class TextGrid, which represents the structured data stored in the files, from the I/O. So there would be a class `TextGrid` and a (static) class `TextGridManager`.

And here is where I am getting lost. Should I implement the reading and writing in their own classes? Should I implement an abstract class BaseTextGridManager and then derive the specialized classes (which, I think, would be what the Open-closed principle would recommend)? But if so, how would the user know which specialized class to instantiate because you have to read the first few bytes of the file before you know how to parse it?

I could certainly find a way to make it work somehow, but I am looking for advice on how to do it elegantly and by following SOLID principles. Any insights would be much appreciated.

### Update:

Thanks to the comments below this question, my current plan is to organize it in the following way:

```
class TextGrid:
{
  // The representation of the TextGrid data
}

class TextGridManager:
{
public:
   static TextGrid readTextGridFile(const std::string& filename);
   static bool writeTextGridFile(const TextGrid& tg, const std::string& filename, const std::string& format);

private:
   TextGridManager(){};
   static TextGrid BinaryTextGridFactory(std::istream& file);
   static TextGrid ShortTextGridFactory(std::istream& file);
   static TextGrid LongTextGridFactory(std::istream& file);
}
```

I welcome any constructive criticism and feedback.

Comment: I'd expect there to be a sniffer function (which may have enough parts and state as to be a class) that determines the file type, and then three different factory functions (which also may have enough state as to warrant being a class) that handle each of the different file formats.  The output of each of the factory functions is a TextGrid.

Comment: Interesting. So that sniffer function would be in the TextGridManager, along with the three Factories producing the TextGrid. And the interface would work something like ``TextGrid tg = TextGridManager::readTextGrid(filename)`` and all the sniffing and different parsing is hidden from the user?

But wouldn't that violate the open-close principle? Because if (for whatever reason) there will be a fourth format of the file, then I could not derive a new manager but would have to add another factory in the old class. As far as I understand the principle, that is exactly what should be avoided.

Comment: @Simon Parsing, in fact, should be hidden away. As a user of your API I don't want to be  annoyed by the details of your implementation. "Here's a file / filename, please give me the data stored therein. If something bad happends during reading/parsing please let me know (by (clearly defined) exception or with an error code)". The top-level function should look something like `TextGrid read_textgrid(std::string_view filename)`.

Comment: Instead of thinking in terms of principles (which are, due to their generalizing nature, controversal anyways IMO) it makes more sense to think of layers/levels of abstractions.

Comment: @Sebastian I appreciate the perspective, but what would that mean here, exactly?

Comment: The sniffer function could return a factory object.  Adding a fourth format would mean creating a new parser that creates a TextGrid from the fourth format, and updating the sniffer to be aware of the fourth factory.  Alternatively, the sniffer function could also be a manager, and the factories register themselves with the sniffer/manager, and sniffer just gives each factory a chance to sniff the data and self-nominate.  More infrastructure, may-or-may-not be overkill.

Comment: @Elijay That does indeed sound like overkill, given that it's unlikely that a fourth format will be added. But just out of curiosity: How would you implement the registration with the manager and nomination of each factory?

Answer (score 0):

For a new format, you will add new writer and let the factory know about it. I am not a C++ guy, that doesn't matter here, however. The syntax is of C# with access modifiers omitted.

```
interface ITextGridReader {
    TextGrid read(filename);
}

class TextGridReader: ITextGridReader {
    // impl read(...);
}

interface ITextGridWriter {
    bool write(filename, textGrid);
}

class BinaryTextGridWriter: ITextGridWriter {
    // imp write(...);
}

class LongTextGridWriter: ITextGridWriter {
    // imp write(...);
}

// Calling code
ITextGridReader reader = new TextGridReader();
TextGrid textGrid = reader.read(...);
ITextGridWriter writer = Factory.CreateTextGridWriter(format);
writer.write(...);
```